# Select row based on the previous row column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the dataframe below. I want to filter this dataframe by ONLY selecting the rows based on the previous column value: if the value in column `typeId` is equal to 6, then select the row after.

| index | typeId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 9 | 6 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 11 | 3 |
| 12 | 6 |
| 13 | 1 |
| 14 | 3 |
| 15 | 6 |
| 16 | 1 |

After filtering the dataframe should look like this:

| index | typeId |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 13 | 1 |
| 16 | 1 |

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), check for equal to 6 with [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), and use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```py
df[df['typeId'].shift().eq(6)]

    typeId
4        1
7        1
10       1
13       1
16       1
```

Comment: I don't think you need to convert to numpy array for boolean indexing.

Comment: @QuangHoang: you are of course right. I was confusing myself with an initial `df[df.shift().eq(6)]`... Fixed that. Thanks!